# Skipping specflow steps and continue execution of following steps in hooks

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, hook, specflow

I want to skip a step (based on some condition) and continue with following steps. For this I want to use BeforeStep hook and if it matches some condition, the current step shall be ignored and continue execution with following steps.

I tried using assert.pass or assert.ignore but it just ends the scenario. I want the test to continue while ignoring the specific step.

Result. I want to have a dynamic scenario that can be used for multiple client. Now not all steps are required for some client. Depending on which client im i want to skip some steps and go to the next step.

For Example:

```
Scenario: Add number 
    Given im on <Client>
    When i add number 5 
    And add number 6 
    And add number 7 
    Then output is <Result>

Examples:
    | Client      | Result  |
    | calculator  | 18      |
    | client2     | 11      |
```

For calculator I might want to be able to run step "add number 7" but for client 2, it must not be done.
Added condition to BeforeStep to check client and step text but can't skip step to next step to get result.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [repro]. Unfortunately we do not have enough information to answer your question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt question was edited

Comment: You are fighting how behavior-driven tests are supposed to be written. Typically a client should have some sort of configuration. It would be best to read that configuration in the test code, and write scenarios specific to those config changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have idea but it will not solve this for each random step.
If you know exactly where it can fail, then put try catch block to this step.
Put a breakpoint in the catch.
once you debug and get to the fail, skip this error by using visual studio - "set next statement" to the row after the Assert.Fail.
Here are pseudo code for this :

```
try
{
     <your step code>
}
catch  (Exception ex) 
{
    <put breakpoint here>
    <log.print(ex);>
    <skip here the Assert.Fail (... )>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The issue with this solution is that i will need to modify each and every step definition implement. this might be a headache. I wanted to find a way to skip the step in the beforeStep hook and it runs to the next steps for execution @Dan6073

Answer (score 0):

I consider 'skipping step' a valid requirement especially for setup steps, when defining a proper client is not justified for a while.

Case in point - I had features with 'Background' steps which create System-Under-Test (SUT) internally. The scenarios would run the Background steps and then run their usual test steps. Now we required to run the same scenarios with external SUT for purpose of bug-reproduction, bug fixes, etc.
It seemed quicker and easier to skip those steps which would create/setup SUT locally and just continue with other steps, assuming there was an external SUT inplace.

I achieved this with help of:

1. Add keyword e.g. `[LocalSetup]` in gherkin step(s) requiring skipping.
2. Create `BeforeTest` Hook, injecting `ScenarioContext`.
3. Using `ScenarioContext.StepContext` in the hook to find if the step is tagged with `[LocalSetup]` and checking some condition then saving Skip/NoSkip decision in the StepContext Dictionary. e.g. `StepContext["SkipSetup"] = true`
4. Modifying Step Implementation, adding initial check for StepContext and returning immediately if .

```
if (scenarioContext.StepContext.ContainsKey("SkipSetup") && scenarioContext.StepContext["SkipSetup"]) 
{ 
    Log.Warning($"Skipping step xyz"); 
    return;
}
```

Works in [Specflow 3.9.40](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/releases/tag/v3.9.40)
Hope this helps.